# Unit test controller with injected service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test that my injected service is being called in my controller.

**login.controller.js**

```
angular.module('exampleModule')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$state', 'AuthService',
    function($state, AuthService) {
      var self = this;

      self.submit = function() {
        AuthService.login(self.credentials)
          .then(function(res) {
            console.log('success');
            $state.go('home');
          }, function(res) {
            if (res.status === 400) {
              console.log('error')
            } 
          });
      };
    }
  ]);
```

**login.service.js**

```
angular.module('exampleModule')
  .factory('AuthService', ['$http',
    function($http) {
      var authService = {};

      authService.login = function(credentials) {
        return $http.post('/api/authenticate', credentials);
          .then(function(res) {
            return res;
          });
      };

      return authService;
    }
  ]);
```

**login.controller.test.js**

```
describe('Controller: LoginCtrl', function() {
  beforeEach(module('exampleModule'));

  var ctrl, authService;

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, AuthService){
    ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl');
    authService = AuthService;
  }));


  describe('submit function', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
      ctrl.submit();
    });

    it('should call AuthService', function() {
      expect(authService.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });    
  });

});
```

How do I properly test whether `AuthService.login` was called? With the way I'm injecting the `AuthService` into my test, I'm getting these errors:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'AuthService.login(self.credentials).then')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock the `login()` method and make it return a promise:

```
describe('Controller: LoginCtrl', function() {
  beforeEach(module('exampleModule'));

  var ctrl, authService, $q;

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$q_, AuthService){
    ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl');
    $q = _$q_;
    authService = AuthService;
  }));


  describe('submit function', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      spyOn(authService, 'login').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
      ctrl.submit();
    });

    it('should call AuthService', function() {     
      expect(authService.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });    
  });
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OajNyJTqmUhDgKTgxXOz?p=preview)